# What is DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001 in pg_stats_activity "query"?

Tags: postgresql

In my return from pg_stat_activity, there are many processes in the "query" column that have the value "DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001".

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` of these connections is probably (and hopefully) `idle`.

That means that the last thing that happened on these connections was to deallocate a prepared statement.

That is kind of funny, because one of the key advantages of prepared statements is to exist for a longer time and be reused. Maybe the application uses a connection pool and wants to “clean” the connection before returning it to the pool.

Anyway, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: right, but on each line that appears such a process, it consumes a  connection right? Because I was having the problem of max connections from my database, and I wanted to know if these processes were influential, because there are really many of them.

Comment: Your application forgets to close the connections (or to return them to the pool). That has nothing to do with the last statement run on the connection, it is a bug in your application.

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel You should have mentioned the max connections problem in the original question. The deallocate is automatically generated by your connection library/framework/whatever when the prepared statement is closed or garbage collected.  But the connection itself is not being closed or garbage collected.  The problem is inside your app, so it would important to know what language you are using for it.

Comment: @jjanes hmmm, I will validate how Code Igniter (PHP) connections are closed, because I am using an already standard basic structure of the project I joined, and there is no connection close flag in the model functions really.

Regarding the question, really, sorry.